# Select statement with 2 different case statement/s format

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've made and tested this SQL script and although the result set is good, but I would like to know if there is any difference between the 2 case statement like in terms of performance for example. And also, does it have a special case if when to use each case statement/s format?

---

```
SELECT
SHIPMENTDT_1 = (CASE ISDATE(ohdr.date1) 
                WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ohdr.date1,102),1,11) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateAdd(Hour,-8,ohdr.date1),108))
                WHEN  0 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),102),1,11) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateAdd(Hour,-8,GETDATE()),108))
               END),

SHIPMENTDT_2 = (CASE 
                   WHEN ISDATE(ohdr.date1) = 1 THEN
                     CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ohdr.date1,102),1,11) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateAdd(Hour,-8,ohdr.date1),108))
                   WHEN ISDATE(ohdr.date1) = 0 THEN
                     CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),102),1,11) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateAdd(Hour,-8,GETDATE()),108))
               END ),   
FROM OHDR
```

Comment: Check this link for difference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: What do the execution plans look like when you break this into two SQL statements and run them separately?

Comment: @santiago_jon They'll be the same.  But then they'd also be the same if you took out the `CASE` expressions entirely and just used `CONVERT`, because the Query Plan doesn't really estimate scalar expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The first form is *slightly* faster, but the difference is *very* slight.

The reason is that the SQL Server T-SQL compiler/optimizer does almost no optimizations of scalar expressions within a row.  So in the first case the expression `ISDATE(ohdr.date1)` is executed once per row, and in the second case, twice.

Nor does the query plan accurately reflect this, nor most other differences in scalar computations.  For instance compare the query plan of your original query to that for the same query where this column:

```
SHIPMENTDT_2 = (CASE 
                   WHEN ISDATE(ohdr.date1) = 1 THEN
                     CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ohdr.date1,102),1,11) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateAdd(Hour,-8,ohdr.date1),108))
                   WHEN ISDATE(ohdr.date1) = 0 THEN
                     CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),102),1,11) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateAdd(Hour,-8,GETDATE()),108))
               END ),
```

is changed to this:

```
SHIPMENTDT_2 = ISDATE(ohdr.date1),
```

You should see no difference, though there's obviously some difference in the total CPU if you execute it, though again, the difference is so small that you may not be able to accurately measure without an extreme test case.